# C# CX509PrivateKey Format

Tags: c#, cryptography, pki

I'm trying to re-use the key pair I generated for creating a `PKCS10` Certificate Signing request, but I cannot figure out what the format of this private key is.

To create the key, I'm using the `CERTENROLLLib CX509PrivateKey` class.

I've set the Private Key ProviderType to `XCV_PROV_RSA_FULL`, and when I export it (trying to figure out what format it is) I use

```
Export("PRIVATEBLOB", EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64)
```

When I export it, the private key always starts with `"BwIAAACkAABSU0E"`

Does anyone know what format this is? I thought ANS.1 DER Encoding always started with `"MII"` or someting like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I answered my own question:

The command

```
Export("PRIVATEBLOB", EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64)
```

exports the private key as a BASE64 encoded CSP blob. In order to import is using the C# RSA libraries I had to use the following:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] CryptoKey = Convert.FromBase64String(base64CspBlob);
rsa.ImportCspBlob(CryptoKey);
```

That did it!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I guessed as much but I wasn't able to test, ran out of time. Horrible API documentation, glad you figured it out.